# Loops- forEach, for, for....of, for...in

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, syntax

I am not able to understand the difference between all these loops, can anyone share a link or some article which will help me understand these loops in more details in terms of efficiency, speed, usability etc.

In the below code, how can I best understand these differences?

```
const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  console.log(digits[i]);
}

const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (const index in digits) {
  console.log(digits[index]);
}

const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
for (const index of digits) {
  console.log(digits[index]);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: If you use `const digits = [2,3,4];` to test with, you'll see that `for..in` is *critically* different from `for..of`.

Comment: In your example it's hard to get the difference between `in` and `of` because your digits array is having the same value as the index. See my answer

Comment: I am a beginner with for...in and for...of loop so had a problem understanding them @HyyanAboFakher - Thanks for the links, I was more interested in the difference between these and when to use which one given the same set of result with the values I used.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - I tried with the values you gave me, it did show the difference but again it did not help me understand their usability and how it works.

Comment: @FlavienVolken - Thanks for pointing out that I had used a wrong array altogether, and had failed to understand exactly how they work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**for loop :** This is the common method of iterating an array where we use `i` as `index` to access the elements in the array `letters`. [MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```js
var letters = ["a","b","c"];
for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
    console.log("Index : "+i, "Value : "+letters[i]);
}
```

**for...in loop :** This loop always iterates over the index. While traversing through the array, the variable `i` will hold the value of the `index` of each element. This can be used when the `index` of the elements needed during iteration. [MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
var letters = ["a","b","c"];
for (var i in letters)
{
    console.log("Index : "+i, "Value : "+letters[i]);
}
```

**for...of loop :** This loop always iterates through the values of the array. While traversing through the array, the variable `i` will hold the value of the element. This can be used if only the `value` of the elements in the array is needed. [MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
var letters = ["a","b","c"];
for (var i of letters)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

**forEach loop :** This loop performs a callback function on each element while traversing through the arr. The parameters to the callback are `currentValue`, `index` of the currentValue, `array` on which the loop is performed. [MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var letters = ["a","b","c"];
letters.forEach(function(value, index, arr){
    console.log("Value : "+value, "Index : "+index, "Complete array : "+arr)
});
```

**Problem in your case :** The code works fine as per the flow. Since you have the array elements equal to its index, it made difficult for you to understand it.

in for...in loop : `index=0` gives `digits[0]=0`,
                   `index=1` gives `digits[1]=1`, and so on.

in for...of loop : `index=0` (where variable `index` holds the value of `digits[0]`), in the `console` statement compiler interprets that value at `index 0` is accessed in the `array d`. Hence it returns the value at `digits[0]`, and so on for all elements.

Answer (score 2):

The common way:

```
for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  console.log(digits[i]);
}
```

Only relies on the condition on `i` for the loop. If the condition `i < digits.length` is not satisfied, the loop will break

Both other versions (using `of` and `in`) are iterators, i.e. they will go and visit all the values of the array. No need to specify how many items to go through.

They however differ:

- `of` keyword will iterate on the **values** of the array
- `in` keyword will iterate on the **index**.

Typically you should use them as follow (example modified to show the difference):

```
const chars = ['A','B','C'];

for (const index in chars) {
  // index will be 0,1,2
  console.log(chars[index]);
}
```

Better if you do not need the index implicitly

```
const chars = ['A','B','C'];
for (const value of chars) {
  // value will be 'A','B','C'
  console.log(value);
}
```