# 'For' loop with arrays to fiind matches doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create a multiple choice quiz and then compare the answers given with other answers(just given as an array). The quiz works and the values get returned, but the 'for' loop at the end seems to get ignored by the program. I was thinking maybe the problem is in the order of execution, i thought maybe placing the `script` tag at the end of the  HTML would help, but it didn't. Then i thought the problem was in the variables declared in the functions locally, so I declared them outside. still nothing. Please shed some light. The code has been changed to be shorter.

```
var userDrinkAnswer;

function submitDrinkAnswer() { // func is called from HTML 
  for (...) {
    userDrinkAnswer = radiosDrink[i].value;
  }
  return userDrinkAnswer;
}

//same with userApologyAnswer;
//same with userPlaceAnswer;

let myAnswers = ['Tea', 'Massage', 'Zoo'];
let hisAnswers = [userDrinkAnswer, userApologyAnswer,userPlaceAnswer];

function findMatch() {
  for (let myAnswersIndex = 0; myAnswersIndex < myAnswers.length; myAnswersIndex++) {
      for (let hisAnswersIndex = 0; hisAnswersIndex < hisAnswers.length; hisAnswersIndex++) {
        if (myAnswers[myAnswersIndex] === hisAnswers[hisAnswersIndex]) {
        document.write(myAnswers[myAnswersIndex]);
      }
    }
  }
}

findMatch();
```

Comment: What console.log(hisAnswers) shows in the top of findMatch functon?

Comment: just shows undefined

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I just simplified it.

**Note:** Don't use `document.write`, as it replaces the whole html on every call.

```js
let userDrinkAnswer='Tea', userApologyAnswer='Massage', userPlaceAnswer = 'Zoo';
let myAnswers = ['Tea', 'Massage', 'Zoo'];
let hisAnswers = [userDrinkAnswer, userApologyAnswer, userPlaceAnswer];

function findMatch() {
    myAnswers.forEach(function(elem, index){
        console.log(elem===hisAnswers[index]);
    });
}

findMatch();
```

Comment: Vignesh, should I pass in arguments in place of elem and index?

Comment: No they will be handled internally. Please refer [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
To know about multiple types of looping methods, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50695019/loops-foreach-for-for-of-for-in/50695510#50695510)

Comment: Thank you, I understand forEach now, but the console shows 'true' 3 times.As I see it, it found 3 matches and says about it, but I want the actual matches to be shown in the console. How can I achieve that?

Comment: then replace it with `console.log(myAnswers[index]);`, if need to show for only equal ones, then add a `if` condition. Please have some try before asking, else you will stay noob. No offence.

Comment: I have tried several times, if I hadn't tried I wouldn't have said what the console shows. Please have respect for less informed and experienced coders and try being less arrogant.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say it. Deep Sorry. Happy coding !