# The following code with generators blocks BrowserSync

Tags: javascript, gulp, generator, browser-sync

I have Gulp with browserSync, that reloads browser every time I save js file. Everything works just fine until I save the following code.

```
    var obj = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 87
}

Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
    var obj = this;
    function* gen() {
        for (var key in obj) {
            yield obj[key];
        }
    }
    return gen();
}

for (var value of obj) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Then if I save something, nothing happens, but my console says that browserSync works normally.
P.S. I was just trying to understand "for of" and stuff.

Comment: To know about the loops [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50695019/loops-foreach-for-for-of-for-in/50695510#50695510)

Comment: Thanks, I believe, I do understand loops in js. It's just always interesting to experiment with new knowledges. Why not to try to implement for of for Objects?